# Azure function plugin for visual studio code not working (mac) - Function Section Missing

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

All tutorials available (including the official microsoft ones), show that when you have the prerequisites installed, and you click on the "Azure" icon on the left, you should see options to "create new project" and view functions and view app instances.

I dont get any of these.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what the tutorials get:

[image]

and

[image]

All of these options are missing, the whole functions tab is missing.

I have .net 6 installed, Azure Functions Core Tools version 4, c# extensions for visual code, and latest azure funcion extension for VS code.
I have restarted computer and vs code several times.

i have also connected to my pay as you go Azure subscription in VS code, and I can browse our subscriptions in vscode.

Any ideas?

VS Code Version: 1.67.2 (Universal)
MacOS 12.4
Architecture M1 Pro Max

Here is the Azure Functions plugin I have installed:

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that… I think it’s related to the azure function version maybe… but you will notice your interface matches the screenshots on the official azure function extension page. Upvoted because I’d also like an answer to this

Answer (score 0):

This is the new update in VS Code environment. Now you can create functions by navigating to `workspace >> Add >> Create function`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I deploy function to azure using the new layout, I tried deploying from workspace but was struck at the "select resource" dialog

Comment: I tried this, but I could not find a way to run the function, neither locally or in azure.  The documentation now seems to be universally incorrect.  Hopefully someone will create some new tutorials based on recent version of VSCode/Azure.  There is no longer a functions tab in the Azure section (or anywhere else)